# ARM Assembly Language dynamic Array declaration

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm

I am trying to translate high level code into ARM instruction sets and I am confused about initializing array within code the code that I am stuck on is

```
int array[] = new int [10]; //dynamically allocating size
array[4] = d;
array[8] = a;
array[2] = c;
```

Do I have to initiate array with .skip at data section or is it possible to allocate memory as it runs? Do I use $sp(stack pointer) for array?

Comment: You appear to have posted your question [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547575/arm-assembly-language-array-declaration). Please remove one of the two questions.

Comment: You have 3 basic options: if you know maximum needed size, you can allocate maximum-possible size as static memory at compile time, then use dynamically only part of it. If the dynamic memory has reasonably small size (thousands of elements) and you need it only temporarily within some function call, then you can allocate that memory on stack. If you need 100k+ of elements or you need them to stay available over longer period of time (across several unrelated functions), then you may want to use heap memory. With C runtime you can use C memory manager hidden under `malloc/free/new/delete` API.

Comment: If you don't have C runtime, just pure asm, then you have to check OS service calls to see how heap memory can be allocated to your process, but usually with real app you then need to create your own memory manager, as the OS heap services are not a good fit for many small allocations. If you are without OS on bare-metal programming, then just check the memory map of your device, *"all your memory are belong to us"* - and use it any way you wish, like reserve some region for dynamic allocations and write your own memory manager.

Answer (score 2):

The direct equivalent is to place 40 in r0 and call operator new using whatever mangled name it has in the C++ ABI you are targeting. The address will be returned in r0, and to handle errors you would need to follow the appropriate exception handling ABI.

If you can replace the corresponding calls to `delete` with calls to `free` (for example if you are converting the entire program) you can call `malloc` instead and therefore not worry about the C++ ABI. Again place 40 (10 ints of 4 bytes each) in r0 and malloc will return a pointer to the allocated memory in r0.

You have not posted enough code to determine if it can be converted to static or stack allocation.